# Need to mock write() method of the ElementTree class from lxml.etree module

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, lxml, cython

I'm writing a method that uses the write method from the ElementTree class from lxml.etree. When writing my tests, I want to mock this so the unit tests don't write a bunch of stuff to my drive.

The code in my file looks something like this

```
    # myapp\gla.py
    from lxml.etree import Element, ElementTree

    def my_func(element):
        root = Element(element)
        xml = ElementTree(root)
        xml.write('path_to_file')
```

The testing look like this:

```
    # tests\test_gla.py
    from unittest import patch
    from myapp.gla import my_func

    @patch('myapp.gla.ElementTree.write')
    def test_my_func(self, mock_write):
        my_func('rootElement')
        mock_write.assert_called_once()
```

I get this

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1171, in patched
        arg = patching.__enter__()
      File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1243, in __enter__
        original, local = self.get_original()
      File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1217, in get_original
        "%s does not have the attribute %r" % (target, name)
    AttributeError: <cyfunction ElementTree at 0x000001FFB4430BC8> does not have the attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer to my own problem.

Re-wrote the test like this:

```
# tests\test_gla.py
from unittest import patch, MagicMock
from myapp.gla import my_func

@patch('myapp.gla.ElementTree')
def test_my_func(self, mock_write):
    mock_write().write = MagicMock()
    my_func('rootElement')
    mock_write().write.assert_called_once()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ElementTree` is a function, not a type](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/etree.pyx#L3113). It returns an object of type `_ElementTree` and it's [that that has the function `write`](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/etree.pyx#L1944).

I haven't tested this (I don't know enough/anything about mock), but I suspect

```
 @patch('myapp.gla._ElementTree.write')
```

should work (although you might also need to import `_ElementTree` yourself).